# RowWise & ColumnWise Total of Output Table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

We are developing MYSQL , ASP.Net application.
I am using TempTable to store output of my stored procedure.

As i have recordset table, Now my concern is how to get TOTAL rowwise & ColumnWise & show it in new row & New column respectively.
Following image will show , What output I expect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c1+c2+c3+c4+c5 c6
  FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(c1), SUM(c2), SUM(c3), SUM(c4), SUM(c5), SUM(c1+c2+c3+c4+c5)
  FROM table1
```

Output:

```
|   C1 |  C2 |   C3 | C4 | C5 |    C6 |
---------------------------------------
|   45 | 416 |    0 |  0 |  0 |   461 |
| 7887 |   0 |    0 |  0 |  0 |  7887 |
|  444 |   0 | 1628 |  0 |  0 |  2072 |
| 8376 | 416 | 1628 |  0 |  0 | 10420 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65feb0/2)** demo

Comment: Petern: Thanks dude, You are helping me a lot.. I appreciate.. Thanks

Comment: @ConstantLearner Great! I'm glad it did :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept/upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get the row with the totals and then add the columns together to get a column with totals:

```
select 
  coalesce(col1, 'Total') col1, 
  sum(col2) col2, 
  sum(col3) col3,
  sum(col4) col4,
  sum(col5) col5,
  sum(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) Total
from yt
group by col1 with rollup;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b71be/3). Result:

```
|   COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | TOTAL |
----------------------------------------------
| INCust |   45 |  416 |    0 |    0 |   461 |
|   none |  444 |    0 | 1628 |    0 |  2072 |
| venddd | 7887 |    0 |    0 |    0 |  7887 |
|  Total | 8376 |  416 | 1628 |    0 | 10420 |
```